# Galaxy GT-P1000, in recovery mode, which button is "Home Key"?

Tags: recovery-mode

In the Galaxy GT-P1000 Tab, when you're in "Recovery Mode", <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> & <kbd>Down</kbd> is used for scrolling. But which button is referred to as <kbd>Ok</kbd> or <kbd>Home Key</kbd> to select?

As far as I know, the <kbd>Menu</kbd> Key, <kbd>Home</kbd> Key, and <kbd>Back</kbd> Key are soft keys that only light up after a full Boot, while in Recovery Mode, these three keys do not come up (lights up).

Right now, after successfully flashing my GT-P1000 stock rom, the instructions says that I should go into recovery mode by pressing <kbd>Volume-Up</kbd> button together with <kbd>Power</kbd> button and enter the recovery mode and use the <kbd>Volume up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> to scroll to "wipe/factory reset" to complete my upgrade. I could not find the "Home Key" that I needed select that option after scrolling to "wipe/factory reset" and my Tab won't boot fully either.

I need these answers quickly to get my Tab working. At the moment, the Tab continues to loop back to rebooting around the Samsung Logo.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have a physical power button? Usually, that is the <kbd>OK</kbd> button in recovery mode.

Comment: The Samsung Galaxy Tab GT-P1000, has physical Power button but when I press the power button, nothing happened, when I press and hold the power, the Tab is turned off. I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

On my GT-P1000 when in recovery mode, the lit up buttons (four light icons on the side where the cable plugs in), the home key is your OK button.